# Multi processing / Multi threading in BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, multithreading, parallelism

I have a test file that looks like this

```
5002 2014-11-24 12:59:37.112 2014-11-24 12:59:37.112 0.000 UDP ...... 23.234.22.106 48104 101 0 0 8.8.8.8 53 68.0 1.0 1 0.0 0 68 0 48
```

Each line contains a source ip and destination ip. Here, source ip is 23.234.22.106 and destination ip is 8.8.8.8. I am doing ip lookup for each ip address and then scraping the webpage using `xidel`. Here is the script.

```
egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" test-data.csv | sort | uniq | while read i #to get network id from arin.net
do
xidel http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/$i -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2] " | sed 's/\/[0-9]\{1,2\}/\n/g'
done | sort | uniq | egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | 
while read j ############## to get other information from ip-tracker.org
do
xidel http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=$j -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[10]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[11]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[12]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[13]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[14]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[15]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[16]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[17]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[18]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[19]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[20]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[21]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[22]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[23]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[24]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[25]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[26]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[27]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[28]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[29]"
done > abcd
```

The first `xidel` is used to scrap [arin](http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/8.8.8.8) and second `xidel` is used to scrap [this](http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=8.8.8.0)

The output of first `xidel` is network id. The ip lookup is done based on network id. The output of second `xidel` is like this

```
IP Address: 8.8.8.0
[IP Blacklist Check]
Reverse DNS:** server can't find 0.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa: SERVFAIL
Hostname: 8.8.8.0
IP Lookup Location For IP Address: 8.8.8.0
Continent:North America (NA)
Country: United States    (US)
Capital:Washington
State:California
City Location:Mountain View
Postal:94040
Area:650
Metro:807
ISP:Level 3 Communications
Organization:Level 3 Communications
AS Number:AS15169 Google Inc.
Time Zone: America/Los_Angeles
Local Time:10:51:40
Timezone GMT offset:-25200
Sunrise / Sunset:06:26 / 19:48
Extra IP Lookup Finder Info for IP Address: 8.8.8.0
Continent Lat/Lon: 46.07305 / -100.546
Country Lat/Lon: 38 / -98
City Lat/Lon: (37.3845) / (-122.0881)
IP Language:    English
IP Address Speed:Dialup Internet Speed
[
Check Internet Speed]
IP Currency:United States dollar($) (USD)
IDD Code:+1
```

As of now, it takes 6 hours to complete this task when there are 1.5 million lines in my test file. This is because the script is running serially.
Is there any way I can divide this task so that the script runs in parallel and the time is reduced significantly. Any help with this would be appreciated.

P.S: I am using a VM with 1 processor and 10 GB RAM

Comment: Have you tried [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). Your 1 processor  VM machine gives me pause however since these downloads are likely IO-bound, there' hope yet

Comment: What do you mean by IO-bound? @1_CR

Comment: See [IO Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound). The majority of the 6 hours your script takes is probably spent waiting on network input

Comment: splitting the file in n parts and launching the script n times is not a good solution for you ?

Comment: @mazs I can try that!

Comment: If there is duplicate work being done, you could filter that down to reduce the external calls to xidel.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am already taking care of duplicate by using `uniq`.` The idea behind using two `xidel` is that first will give me network id and second `xidel` is used for ip look up. This makes sure that I am not doing ip lookup for Ip address in the same same subnet. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The first grep, that returns IPs, is not going through uniq...

Comment: @Jeff Schaller Thanks for the pointer. But the bottle neck is opening TCP connection for each ip address. That is where I need to optimize. Any help with that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust -jXXX% as needed:

```
PARALLEL=-j200%
export PARALLEL

arin() {
    #to get network id from arin.net
    i="$@"
    xidel http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/$i -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2] " |
    sed 's/\/[0-9]\{1,2\}/\n/g'
}
export -f arin

iptrac() {
    # to get other information from ip-tracker.org
    j="$@"
    xidel http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=$j -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[10]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[11]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[12]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[13]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[14]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[15]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[16]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[17]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[18]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[19]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[20]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[21]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[22]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[23]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[24]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[25]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[26]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[27]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[28]" -e "//table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[29]"
}
export -f iptrac

egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" test-data.csv | sort | uniq | 
parallel arin |
sort | uniq | egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | 
parallel iptrac > abcd
```

Comment: Can you explain first 2 lines of the code ? Where is PARALLEL(first line) being used?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES If you prefer you can just write -j200% after parallel. It will do the same.

Comment: It worked! With one core it was fast but there were packet loss. With 4 cores 6 hours of time reduced to mere 7 mins. Thank you.